# Symfony 4 controllers in sub folders producing error

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Just a quick question as to why I'm getting this

> The autoloader expected class "App\Controller\Admin\AdminUnitController" to be defined in file "/home/glen/public_html/businessdirectory.glendev.local/vendor/composer/../../src/Controller/Admin/AdminUnitController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo in /home/glen/public_html/businessdirectory.glendev.local/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/home/glen/public_html/businessdirectory.glendev.local/config/services.yaml").

I have AdminUnitController.php with class name AdminUnitController. All was well until I decided I want the admin controllers in their own sub folder like this:

```
Controller\Admin\AdminUnitController.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the autoloader message, your issue is quite clear, your file is indeed where it should be but your class or namespace is wrong.

I would guess you changed the file structure but did not adapt your namespace.

Given the file *`src\Controller\Admin\AdminUnitController.php`*

Your class should look like this (pay specific attention at the namespace):

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

class AdminUnitController 
{
    // some code here
}
```

That is actually not a Symfony behavior you are facing here, but one of composer, that serves Symfony with the autoloader and that uses PSR-4 class autoloading convention.

**For Reference**

1) see your `composer.json` that have those lines:

```
{
  // some definitions here
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  // some more definitions here
}
```

2) see the PSR-4 naming convention: and especially the examples in their documentation: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/#3-examples

Comment: interesting, I didn't realise Symfony cared about the controller namespace like this. Makes sense. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Although doing that produces a new error: Class "App\Controller\AdminBusinessController" used for service "App\Controller\AdminBusinessController" cannot be found.

Comment: Most likely for the same kind of reason, you changed the location of the controller into `src\Controller\Admin\AdminBusinessController` but did not adapted the namespace of the class `AdminBusinessController`. Or you are having, somewhere in your porject a `use App\Controller\AdminBusinessController;` that should be adapted to `use App\Controller\Admin\AdminBusinessController;`

Comment: As for the "I didn't realise Symfony cared about the controller namespace", well Symfony does not care. Composer, that serves the autoloader to Symfony, in the other hand, does, and you can see the edited answer about how that *PSR-4* autoloader naming convention behaves

Comment: Thanks i will have a look. Sorry if it sounds dumb, i've only recently moved to symfony from using CI for years (btw symfony trumps CI!!!)